# Adapt EEPROM EMULATOR STM32F103VE

Tags: stm32, memory, flash, eeprom, emulator

I'm working with STM32F103VE and STM32F746, and i want to use my Flash memory as EEPROM EMULATOR for writing and reading data easily.

I have searched for axemples of Emulation of EEPROM for my board but i found exemple of those boards '' STM32F0xx and STM32L4'' and i want to adapt the codes eeprom.h and eeprom.c to my boards.

What i should change? and where?

it's my first time with STM32.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you studied the code in eeprom.h and eeprom.c? Maybe you could add links to the files you are looking?

Comment: This is really too broad to be addressed here.  Besides, ST already provides applicable guidance quite readily found with a search, for example for the F1 series https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00165693.pdf

Answer (score 2):

STM32F0 and STM32F1 devices have uniform 1k or 2k flash erase blocks, depending on the exact part number (check the respective manuals, see below), the STM32L4 series has 2k flash blocks, so porting the library from F0 to F1 should be the easiest.

You have to adjust the flash size, the flash register accesses (register fields can have different functions between F0 and F1), and the flash write accesses. Pay attention to the required write unit size (byte, halfword or word), it might be dependent on a few things including the [supply voltage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57752689/how-to-use-the-vrefint-in-stm32f103-bluepill/57753188#57753188).

The STM32F0 flash interface is documented in the product *Reference Manual*, the STM32F1 has a separate *Flash Programming Manual* on the ST website.

Keep in mind that erasing of a flash block, which is from time to time necessary, can take a significant amount of time, up to 40ms for a 2k block, up to 4 *seconds* for a 256k block, and the cpu is halted during erase, unless it's a dual-bank device, or all code is moved to RAM, which is quite tricky.

The STM32F7 series has a vastly different flash layout, with non-uniform erase block size ranging from 32k to 256k, porting would take some significant effort.